# how to register extension name and icon in TYPO3 dashboard?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

Hello I am newer using TYPO3 version 10 and I need to create an extension basically I need to register my extension under **dashboard > web > my_extension**

here is my code :

```
defined('TYPO3_MODE') || die();

/**
 * Registers a Backend Module
 */
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addModule(
    'web',
    'MyExt',
    '',
    '',
    [
        'routeTarget' => \Localizationteam\L10nmgr\Controller\Manager::class . '::mainAction',
        'access'      => 'user,group',
        'name'        => 'web_MyExt',
        'icon'        => 'EXT:gpi_localizer/Resources/Public/Icons/Extension.svg',
        'labels'      => 'LLL:EXT:gpi_localizer/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf',
    ]
);
```

[image]

I don't know why the icon is shown black and the extension name does not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have LLL:EXT:gpi_localizer/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf in place which must at least contain the title of your module.

Regarding the icon I have no idea. Maybe it's somehow transparent?